# AuthorizeAttribute Redirect After user Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using default Web Application template for MVC4 in Visual Studio. How can I write Authorize Attribute to redirect user after succesfull login? This attribute should look like this: [UserRedirect("username")] whether anyone use "username" login redirect should be made. Where do I apply this attribute? To the login page or index? Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override OnAuthorization method of AuthorizeAtribute

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
 public class UserRedirectAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
 {
       public string UserName{ get; set; }

       public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
       {
           base.onAuthorization(filterContext);
           if(base.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext) == true)
           {
               //here put all the a logic for redirect condition ()              
                 if(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Equals(this.UserName,StringComparer.Ordinal)
                 {
                   //if you should do the redirect

                       filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                            new RouteValueDictionary(
                                new
                                    { 
                                        controller = "Redirect controller name", 
                                        action = "Redirect action name" 
                                    })
                            );
                  }
             }
        }
   }
```

Regarding the usage:

If it is an authorize attribute that is going to replace default authorize attribute you should on any authorized Action/Controller

**EDIT**:

Based on your last comment you don't have to use an attribute at all. Just add the redirect logic at the end of your login action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
   bool userAuthenticationResult = // here goes your authentication logic
   if(userAuthenticationResult && HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Equals(this.UserName,StringComparer.Ordinal))
   {
      //setup cookie/token any other things you need for the authentication to work
      return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName");
   }

}
```

Comment: I need to do this redirection only once after logon to the account, do I really need to add this attribute to every action in controlller? Could this attribute work alongside the original [Authorize] ?

Comment: In this case you don't have to use an attribute at all. Just add the redirect logic at the end of your login action